# ¿Cómo copio los valores de una matriz en una nueva matriz en java?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

soy nueva programando y me gustaría resolver una duda que tengo.
Quisiera pasar los valores de una matriz ya generada en una matriz vacía.
Por ejemplo:

```
int [ ] [ ] matriz = new int [3] [3];
int [ ] [ ] matrizVacia = null;

for(int filas=0; filas<3; filas++) {
    for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 3; columnas++) {
         matriz[filas][columnas] = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);
    }
}

matrizVacia[ ] [ ] = matriz [filas] [columnas];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder hacer lo que quieres en primer lugar tienes que definir un espacio a `matrizVacia` que sea igual o mayor al de `matriz`. Lo suyo es que sea igual si sólo quieres almacenar esa matriz pero si quieres almacenar más cosas y es mayor el programa sigue funcionando. No puedes definirla como null ya que si no te dará error `NullPointerException`.

Por otro lado, para hacer lo que quieres, la asignación tienes que hacerla dentro del bucle for. Y más importante, para cualquier asignación de un array debes indicar la posición en las que quieres almacenar el valor. Si no le indicas las posiciones te dará error de compilación, ya que no sabe dónde almacenarlo.

```
int [ ] [ ] matriz = new int [3] [3];
    int [ ] [ ] matrizVacia = new int [3][3];

    for(int filas=0; filas<3; filas++) {
        for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 3; columnas++) {
             matriz[filas][columnas] = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);
             matrizVacia[ filas] [columnas] = matriz [filas] [columnas];
            System.out.print(matrizVacia[filas][columnas] +" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

He añadido las líneas `System.out.print(matrizVacia[filas][columnas] +" ");` y `System.out.println();` para que te aparezca por consola la matriz pero son prescindibles.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] matriz = new int[3][3];
//Importante que el array origen quepa en el de destino
int[][] matrizVacia = new int[3][3];

for(int filas = 0; filas < 3; filas++) {
    for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 3; columnas++) {
         matriz[filas][columnas] = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);
    }
}

//Copiamos el contenido de un array en otro
for(int filas = 0; filas < 3; filas++) {
    System.arraycopy(matriz[filas], 0, matrizVacia[filas], 0, matriz[filas].length);
}

System.out.println(matrizVacia[2][2]);
}
```

Con esto copiarias los valores, pero si lo que quieres es tener una referencia al array original con

```
matrizVacia = matriz;
```

Te vale, lo que pasa es que así, el valor que cambies en uno se verá reflejado en el otro